# Does $c_n^2$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_n$ be a positive decreasing sequence s.t. $\sum a_n$ converges.
>
> Define: $A_0 = \{ 0 \}$.
>
> $A_i = \{ 1/n  | a_{i-1} < 1/n <a_i\}$.
>
> Assume $A_i$ is well defined and not empty.
>
> Now define the sequence $c_n$:
>
> $c_i$ = $\sum\{ p\in A_i\}$.
>
> Prove $c_n^2$ converges for $a_n = 1/n^2$.
>
> Does $c_n^2$ converges without additional assumptions on $a_n$?

I believe $c_n^2$ converges for $a_n = 1/n^2$.

If i am not wrong then each $c_i$ term can be bounded since:

$c_i = \sum_{k = 0}^{(i+1)^2 - i^2} \frac{1}{k+i^2} < \frac{(i+1)^2 - i^2}{i^2}$.

But I am kinda lost with part 2 of the question - without extra assumptions on $a_n$.

Any hints will be appericiated.